If $x > 0$ is a real number and $x+\frac{1}{x} \leq 7$ then the maximum value of the expression $x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}$ is...?
The problem
If $x > 0$ is a real number and $x+\frac{1}{x} \leq 7$ then the maximum value of the expression $x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}$ is...?
my idea
We know that $x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}= (x- \frac{1}{x})(x+ \frac{1}{x})$
I thought of squaring $x+\frac{1}{x} \leq 7$ and got that $x^2+\frac{1}{x^2} \leq 47$
I don't know what to do forward. All I know is that the answer is $21 \sqrt{5}$
I hope one of you can help me! Thanks!

The set of all $x> 0$ satisfying $x + 1/x \le 7$ is an interval whose boundaries can easily computed with a quadratic equation. Also $x^2 - 1/x^2$ is increasing in $x$ ...

@MartinR Do you talk about the fact that $ 2 \leq x+1/x \leq 7$??? I don't understand what are you talking about

As $x$ gets bigger, $x^2$ increases, $\frac{1}{x^2}$ decreases, and $x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}$ increases. So you want $x$ to be as large as possible, and satisfy $x+\frac{1}{x}\le 7$. Can you carry on from there?

@ChrisLewis Nope... the thing that confuse me if that x should be real...sorry

Which positive $x$ satisfy the inequality $x + 1/x \le 7$? Perhaps try to plot that function first.

@MartinR I didnt learned about functions yet

@ThomasAndrews Yeah, but we need the maximum

$(x-\frac{1}{x})^2 = x^2 - 2 + \frac{1}{x^2} = (x+\frac{1}{x})^2 - 4$
So if $x+\frac{1}{x} \leq 7 $, then we have  $x-\frac{1}{x} < \sqrt{7^2 - 4} = 3\sqrt{5}$
Thus $x^2 - \frac{1}{x^2} \leq 7 * 3\sqrt{5} = 21 \sqrt{5}$
It is also easy to verify that when $x = \frac{7+3\sqrt{5}}{2}$, the maximum value $21\sqrt{5}$ can be achieved.

Since $x>0$, multiplying the inequality by $x$ is permissible and we get $x^2-7x+1 \le 0 \implies \frac{7-3\sqrt{5}}{2} \le x \le \frac{7+3\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and since $x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}$ is increasing, take the maximum possible value of $x$ to get the maximum value of the expression.
